SSRS subscription parameters storing numeric values instead of names
I am working on extracting the subscription parameters from the SSRS report server DB. I have parsed the XML out so that I get the parameter name and its value. See here. However, a lot of the values for these reports are stored as some sort of numeric value - almost like it's an ID. The numeric value is of course useless to me and it wouldn't be feasible to go through hundreds of reports on the webpage to find out what the parameter values really mean.
Here is an example: The value for parameter name Facility may be stored as 152540000001 but represented as 'Site1" on the actual webpage.
Has anyone ran into this before? I tried searching all of the tables and couldn't find the id or string value in any. Would like to know how SSRS is mapping these numeric values to the string on the webpage so I can pull them.

If it's an ID, it's an ID in your database; we can't tell you where that value in your database comes from. I don't think this question is answerable.

Have you tried to lookup the related report in the Catalog and shred its Content XML to resolve the /Report/ReportParameters/ReportParameter information? It won't have the names, either, but at least you can determine their source.

@AlwaysLearning I did end up learning that the ids where pulled in from a completely different database. The report server was in other words joint with another database and I did not know that. I ended up having to go into that db, save the result sets of the id and its value name into a csv, iterate through the original result set containing the report params, and map the ids so I could replace them with the appropriate name within a python dataset.
